# Binding two data classes to one fragment - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been busy learning android dev with kotlin lately, and I managed to do some fun stuff but lately got stuck in one place. The problem is that I don't know how to get username binding in my fragment, I bined one data class which is a PostItem data class, and I bind the files in the fragment with coresponding fields of this class but my problem is that I just can't bind the username. And my question is how to do it?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".fragments.PostsFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="post"
            type="com.lswarss.ing_project.domain.PostItem" />

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.lswarss.ing_project.domain.UserItem" />

    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.242"
        android:text="@{post.title}" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019"
        android:text="@{post.body}"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_user"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:text="@{user.username}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/post_comment"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.144"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_body"
        tools:text="Username" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_comment"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="comments"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_body"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.483"
        tools:text="comments" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/usericon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_body"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/user_img" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my post fragment, and I thought about doing some function which will fetch the username by the id from PostItem class, but maybe there is some other better way?

Here is the link to my repo with the project on master branch is the most fresh code right now https://github.com/LSWarss/ing_project

sory if the question is stupid but I just can't find any good reference for this and I'm really noob in android so please guide me :D

Comment: Can you please post your java class as well?

Comment: What do you mean by java class?

Comment: @LSWarss he meant kotlin class of the fragment...